# Portal for ArcGIS no items in content

Tags: arcgis-portal

I went to refresh the share properties on a feature service this morning and when I got to our Portal site all items were missing from the contents tab as well as in all groups. We now seem to have no content at all on the site. On Portal admin page I can see that the items still exist and are showing up in the applications pointing to their rest services. I’ve looked online for a solution which entailed reindexing and restarting the Portal for ArcGIS service as well as restarting the entire server. This did not resolve the issue. To note, the count of data items in datastore and count of index do not match even after reindexing (index counts are all at 0).

Any other ideas of how I can get the items to show back up on our Portal site?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: Yes I did. Had to restore server prior to reindexing items in datastore.